# Вычисляемые поля в БД

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

1) Если в программе необходима возможность корректировать  вычисленные суммы НДС и суммы без НДС, то в БД необходимо создавать отдельные поля а не вычисляемые?

2) Вычисления и проверка корректности переносить в логику программы?

3) Можно ли использовать запросы при создании вычисляемого поля в SQl server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Да

> Вычисляемый столбец не может быть целевым столбцом инструкций INSERT или UPDATE.

2. Да, потому что проверка введенного значения на стороне БД это либо триггер либо чек констрейнт, не то не то, нативно не вернет вам ошибку на сторону приложения.
3. А вот тут есть нюансы, ибо можно использовать только столбцы текущей таблицы, и это не совсем запрос, это скорее выражение

**Можно**: column1 + column2 / column3
**Нельзя**: SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = a

Подробнее о: [Указание вычисляемых столбцов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: то есть если мне в итоговой выборке нужны итоги сумм на основе вычислений по нескольким таблица и условиям (например, взять из другой таблицы стоимость работ только внешних соисполнителей по данному этапу работ) это в вычисляемом столбце таблицы не выполнить? Или я смогу запросами решить эту проблему?

Comment: @Spiffo в вычисляемом не выполнить. Только запрос к двум или более таблицам в зависимости от вашей схемы.